# Graph a function of two variables online, with the output rendered as color

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, math-software, visualization, online-resources

Are there any online utilities to graph a function of two variables online, with the output rendered as color in some way (for example, red to green, black to white, hue, etc...) Wolfram Alpha comes close, but divides it into discrete colors. I would like the output to still be seen continuously.

Comment: The plotting functions in Mathematica have dozens of parameters that let you control the appearance of the output. I would guess that the same is true of Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @bubba Yes, if you give them monies.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha will do this. What you're essentially asking is for a colour coded contour plot. For instance see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5BCos%5Bx%5D%20%2B%20Cos%5By%5D,%20%7Bx,%200,%204%20Pi%7D,%20%7By,%200,%204%20Pi%7D%5D) for an example